# Add another item button goes missing with unlimited, repeating dates

Tags: 7, datetime

Unlimited + repeating date fields seem to not work together. I would like to be able to add unlimited date fields that may or may not have repeating functionality.

I currently have both unlimited and repeating options enabled on a date field:

[image: add description here]

But the "Add another item" button is missing when utilizing the field on node creation:

[image]

It should be more like this except with the repeat functionality as well:

[image]

Is this possible? Has anyone seen this issue before?

Thanks!

Comment: **[I did a test](http://i.stack.imgur.com/v5LqI.jpg)** when creating a node and could not reproduce your issue, everything worked fine for me. The thing I noticed is that your time has its own box. Did you install a contrib module for that? Perhaps that module is causing this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an issue. According to documentation found here - https://www.drupal.org/node/295239

> If the Date Repeat API is enabled, you will see 'repeating' as an alternative to allowing 'unlimited' multiple values.

Comment: Well is it possible for my described behavior to happen?

Comment: you could use [fields collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection) with your date field in it. Everytime you would want to add another date, you would click on "add another". This approach will add another level of nesting to your form field, so it may look kind of awkward - nothing that can't be fixed with some css. Plus having your field wrapped in field collection will add additional effort and/or constraints if you'd want to target such field(s) via Rules of Views, but it's definitely doable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think I can get the desired functionality with fields collection :)